# Get the logged-in User's Name on Mac OS X 10.5

Tags: cocoa, macos

Please let me know of any example code or Cocoa API to get the logged-in user's name on Mac OS X 10.5.

Comment: its polite to accept answers that have helped you, btw.

Answer (score 31):

The Foundation framework provides functions to obtain the user name and the full user name:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString *userName = NSUserName();
NSString *fullUserName = NSFullUserName();
```

Comment: Worth mentioning you don't typically have to import Foundation in a Mac app as the class file templates are all set up correctly (import Cocoa, which is the umbrella framework for Foundation and AppKit on the Mac) to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

If your process running in as root.
And you want current login user then you can use
`SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(SCDynamicStoreRef store, uid_t *uid, gid_t *gid)`
which is present in systemConfiguretion framework.

use it as `CFStringRef cfName = SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(NULL, NULL, NULL);`

you can get other info by passing parameter to function.